# Pros and cons of directly interconnecting routers and firewalls vs via switch in an enterprise-network?

Tags: switch, router, firewall, ieee-802.1ax

In a medium-sized enterprise network, let's say you have a pair of datacenter switches, a pair of distribution switches, a pair of internal core routers, a pair of firewalls, and a pair of edge routers running BGP connected to the Internet.

When designing **physical interconnects** between those devices, **what are pros and cons of connecting these devices** (such as core routers to firewalls, or firewalls to edge routers) **directly vs connecting them all only to switches (and using VLANs to facilitate communication)**?

In both cases proper link aggregation is set up (each device in a pair to both other devices).

Comment: Connecting datacenter switches and distribution switches by additional switches? I think you need to elaborate. Please add diagrams for both scenarios to your question, including the planned device types. Note that for most devices link aggregation is limited to connections between two units and there's no standard for MC-LAG. Also note that homework is explicitly off-topic here, see the [help].